# Java process swing InputStream and OutputStream operations

Tags: java

I have `slcanterm.exe` command line utility that perform terminal functions with my USB-CAN adapter, connected to PC.
I need to start this utility from Java application, then in loop write and read to/from this terminal.
My problem is that I can't get InputStream and OutputStream worked together:

```
System.out.println( "hello" );
String line;
OutputStream stdin = null;
InputStream stderr = null;
InputStream stdout = null;

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("cmd.exe");
stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
stdout = process.getInputStream ();

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));

line = "slcanterm.exe" + "\n";
writer.write(line );
writer.flush();

// If I uncomment this line reader.readLine() loop is stucked
//writer.close();

while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)     
    System.out.println ("[Stdout] " + line);

System.out.println( "buy" );
```

If I not close `writer` stream the `while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)`
stay stucked.
I need perform to work `reader.readLine ()` and `writer.write(line )` together in loop.
Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.out.println( "hello" );
    String line;

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("cmd.exe /c slcanterm.exe");

    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stderr));

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String err;
                while ((err = error.readLine ()) != null)     
                    System.out.println ("[Stderr] " + err);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }}.start();

    while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)     
        System.out.println ("[Stdout] " + line);

    System.out.println( "buy" );
```

Comment: Thank you! Putting `InputStreamReader` in another thread helps. Is there any kind of non-blocking `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: You don't really need the thread in this case. Since you are executing a single command it will terminate at the end and all streams will be closed. So you could read `stderr` and then `stdout` in sequence because it would not block.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code is (basically) correct. However, i ran into a similar problem with another process that did not respond well on closing its input stream. if you close the input stream (writer) of the process, the process actually sees that his input stream is closed and fails when it tries to read from it. In my case, the process i started did not respond well when his read failed. This seems to be the same problem.

2) You may circumvent this alltogether by starting slcanterm.exe directly without cmd.exe.

3) Another possibility i see is that you only append a "\n", maybe cmd.exe requires a "\n\r".

Answer (score 1):

The output stream will stay open until the process exits. The process exits when it decides to terminate, it is explicitly killed, or implicitly killed by closing the input stream, for example.

This means that your `readLine` will block until there is more output from `cmd.exe` but, since you don't send more commands, there isn't any. And it won't ever be.

In the simple case, you can either close the input or write `exit` command, to close the console. If `slcanterm.exe` is the only program you want to run then you could start that process directly. If you want to run more commands then you need a way to detect an error (do not ignore the error stream) or to detect that the output of the command has terminated. If the command you run does not have a consistent *last* line then you can write `echo ---MARKER---` to `stdin` and detect when that line appears (it means that the last command has terminated and the `echo` as been executed).

Many possibilities. It depends on what you want to do.

The following class demonstrates the simple technique I was suggesting. Also, it ensures `echo off` and that everything that is not the command output is ignored (because `cmd.exe` outputs every input character).

```
class CommandRunner implements Closeable {

    private Process cmd;
    private OutputStreamWriter stdin;
    private BufferedReader stderr;
    private BufferedReader stdout;

    private static class ArtificialOutput {
        public List<String> inputLines;
        public String finalMarker;

        public ArtificialOutput(List<String> inputLines, String finalMarker) {
            super();
            this.inputLines = inputLines;
            this.finalMarker = finalMarker;
        }
    }

    public CommandRunner() throws IOException {
        cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
        stdin = new OutputStreamWriter(cmd.getOutputStream());
        stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getErrorStream()));
        stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));   

        // turn off echo of commands (also skips any console header lines)
        execute("echo off", StdinWriter.WRITE_NOTHING, StdoutProcessor.IGNORE);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        stdin.close();
        stdout.close();
        stderr.close();
        cmd.destroy();
    }

    public void execute(String command, StdinWriter writer, StdoutProcessor processor) throws IOException {             
        processOutput(executeCommand(command, writer), processor);
    }

    private ArtificialOutput executeCommand(String command, StdinWriter writer) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        // add command as input line
        lines.add(command);

        // add all custom input lines
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (OutputStreamWriter bufferWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer)) {
            writer.write(bufferWriter);
        }

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray())))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        }

        // add stdout and sterr markers as input lines
        String marker = "--- MARKER " + System.currentTimeMillis() + Math.random();
        lines.add("echo " + marker + ">&2");
        lines.add("echo " + marker);

        // write everything to stdin
        for (String line : lines) {
            stdin.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        stdin.flush();

        // our artificial outputs (with echo off) are the input lines and the closing marker
        return new ArtificialOutput(lines, marker);
    }

    private void processOutput(ArtificialOutput artificialOutput, StdoutProcessor processor) throws IOException {
        byte[] output = readUntilMarker(artificialOutput, stdout);
        byte[] errors = readUntilMarker(artificialOutput, stderr);

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            processor.processError(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(errors))));
        }

        processor.processOuput(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(output))));
    }

    private byte[] readUntilMarker(ArtificialOutput artificialOutput, BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(buffer))) {;
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // ignore input lines because cmd.exe outputs every input character
                if (artificialOutput.inputLines.remove(line)) {
                    continue;
                }

                // the final marker indicates the command has ended
                if (line.equals(artificialOutput.finalMarker)) {
                    break;
                }

                // everything else is the command output
                writer.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }

        return buffer.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

Having this class you can do this in your program:

```
try (CommandRunner cmd = new CommandRunner()) {
    cmd.execute("dir", StdinWriter.WRITE_NOTHING, StdoutProcessor.PRINT);
    cmd.execute("echo something", StdinWriter.WRITE_NOTHING, StdoutProcessor.PRINT);
}
```

Comment: Yes! `readLine()` will block. Is there is proper way to read from Stream without blocking?? Using `InputStreamReader` instead of `BufferedReader` don't resolve the problem. Also stucked.

Comment: Like I said, the simplest way is to do `stdin.write(command + System.lineSeparator() + "echo ---MARKER---" + System.lineSeparator())` and then check if any line you read is "---MARKER---". If you find that line you know the command as finished and you should not read any line (it will block) until you write another command.

Comment: I've added a sample class that may help. It demonstrates the technique I was suggesting, of using a final marker.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the output of slcanterm.exe then you can just read the stdin OutputStream until it gets closed (i.e. the program stopped).

Closing stdin, stdout or stderr of a program will cause it to terminate most of the time (since that's the standard behavior of most shells), so you want to avoid calling close() on them.

If you want to execute more than one program in a row, I'd recommend writing a batch file with proper error handling and output filtering and execute that with Java (or maybe even just executing them one by one, starting multiple processes). Going through cmd.exe will almost never be worth the hassle of dealing with inputting commands multiple times and waiting for responses (and you're also losing a great deal of portability by using cmd.exe).

All that being said, the reason for your readLine() call to be stuck is, that there's nothing on stdout. My bet would be that cmd.exe needs a Windows line break ("\n\r") to execute commands or that slcanterm.exe doesn't output anything (or maybe just to stderr?).